# How to get CommandBar from XAML resources in C++/CX?

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I defined CommandBar in the page resources:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CommandBar x:Name="mainCommandBar" x:Key="mainCommandBar">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="AppBarButton"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Cancel" Label="AppBarButton"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.Resources>
```

And then in the page constructor I assign this commandBar to TopAppBar:

```
TopAppBar = mainCommandBar;
```

But I get an error "Element not found".

If I create CommandBar programmatically - all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the entry in the ResourceDictionary prior to assigning it to TopAppBar because an instance of Control may not appear multiple times in XAML tree.

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Resources->Remove(L"mainCommandBar");
    TopAppBar = mainCommandBar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to retrieve the CommandBar Style resource out of a page’s resource dictionary and then assign this commandBar to TopAppBar.

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CommandBar^ commandBarStyle = (CommandBar^)this->Resources->Lookup("mainCommandBar");
    CommandBar^ TopAppBar = commandBarStyle;

}
```

Comment: You are assigning to a local variable TopAppBar. But I need to assign to TopAppBar property of the page (Page.TopAppBar in XAML).